# Inferring r2 and pvalues in a scatterplot between observed and modelled values

Tags: r, p-value, scatterplot

I have a dataframe, consisting of modelled and MODIS observed data. The values represent mean GPP for the year 2000,2001,2002,2003 .. till 2010.

```
A tibble: 11 x 2
   MODIS  Modelled
   <dbl> <dbl>
 1  0.39  0.4 
 2  0.39  0.4 
 3  0.4   0.39
 4  0.38  0.43
 5  0.38  0.41
 6  0.39  0.45
 7  0.42  0.42
 8  0.41  0.44
 9  0.41  0.45
10  0.4   0.44
11  0.41  0.48
```

I calulcate the r2 and p value in R by following code:

```
summary(lm(modelled~observed, data=df1))$r.squared 
cor.test(df1$MODIS,df1$Modelled)
```

The r2 is 0.14 and p value is 0.25
What can be inferred from this pvalue and r2 value? Does the p value indicate that there is a weak agreement between the modis and modelled values? Kindly help me to understand how pvalue can help to infer r2.

Detailed lm output

```
Call:
lm(formula = modelled ~ observed, data = df1)

Residuals:
     Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max 
-0.03959 -0.02186  0.00268  0.01428  0.04268 

Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)
(Intercept)   0.1203     0.2512   0.479    0.643
observed      0.7732     0.6305   1.226    0.251

Residual standard error: 0.02648 on 9 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.1432,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.04798 
F-statistic: 1.504 on 1 and 9 DF,  p-value: 0.2512
```

Comment: It is a whole dataset? The P-value you wrote came from the 'cor.test', correct?
Could you provide detailed lm output?

Comment: I attatched the lm output with details. Yes this is the whole dataset.  It covers the years from 2000-2010

Comment: Yes, thank you. As you can see, the R-squared is equal to 0.1432, not 10.14 as you said. It is not too much, especially that your dataset contains only 11 rows. You may conclude that the relation of the x and y is rather weak and may come from the random variation rather than strong relation.

Comment: I apologize for the mistype error. Moreover, what does the p value suggest in this case? Your statement "your dataset contains only 11 rows", does that mean if I take more number of years then I will be able to see a more clearer picture of scatter plot? Meaning more points = more clearer result between the relation of modelled and observed.

Comment: I think you need to go back a few steps because if you're trying to show that your model is correlated to the observed predictions, this is not really the way to do it. You should separate a test set from your data, train your model on the training set, then calculate R-squared in the test set and look at your residuals with the observed data.

Comment: In general yes, if you have more observations your power of inference increases. 
The p-value 0.2512 is referred to results of the F-test. The value is very high, thus you cannot reject a null hypothesis (null hypothesis is that your model fit the data not better than the model with no predictor). It is in brief, I suggest you read more about F-test but also about linear regression it will help clarify your problem.

Comment: @csgroen I agree with your idea, however, it could be difficult to do with 11 observations.

Comment: @Jakub maybe do cross-validation instead? Since you only have 11 observations, something like 3-fold CV, for estimating the model metrics from CV.